# Cube Glowing in Blender 2.82.7

Tags: mesh, objects, light

My objects I add in blender are glowing? Does anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having trouble when moving your object too? Because I had the same problems before. To solve, deselect everything in edit mode and then go to object mode. You can click to an empty place for deselecting everything or doubleclick on <kbd>A</kbd> fastly.

Comment: I do not have trouble moving a object. But it solved it!

Comment: Nice! I am happy that you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have activated "Flat Shading" on accident. To fix this, go to the top  right where the viewport display options are, click the dropdown and switch to "Studio" or "Matcap" lighting.

- **Studio lighting** gives a clean look and is useful in many places
- **Matcap lighting** gives many more looks to the object to help users see geometry more clearly. Click the orb and select one to change.
- The last one is **Flat lighting**. It has no shading whatsoever so you will only see the profiles of objects. Might help with speeding up the viewport in intense scenes but I don't see much reason to use it otherwise.

[image]